# Sending a byte through the serial port - custom class python

Tags: python

I would like to send a byte (preferably `0000 0001`) through the serial port using a custom class Python script, but unfortunately I am new to Python with a background in Basic. I have included code below of an attempt I found on the lab PC from a colleague who has now left.

From what I can tell, the contents of pulseValue will be sent. However, when I set pulseValue to `'1'` in the eyetracking program I'm using, more than one bit is sent. I think the program requires pulseValue to be set, otherwise I think I could `write(bytes(*something*))`.

I was wondering if the code below looks anything like it will do what I need it to do?

```
import sreb
import serial

class pulseSend(sreb.EBObject):

    def __init__(self):
        sreb.EBObject.__init__(self)
        self.serial = serial.Serial(0)

    def sendPulse(self,pulseValue):
        """RETURN:0""" 
        self.serial.write(pulseValue)


        return 0
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your markdown was a little off - I've updated your question a bit to clarify. If this isn't correct you can always go back and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

`'1'` is a string, containing the character 1 (which has ASCII code 65), not the number 1.  This is 01000001 in binary, so yes, there's more than one bit set.  Your requirements aren't very clear, but I think you want to write `chr(1)` for the character with only the lowest bit set.  You may prefer to write `chr(0x01)` (hexadecimal) or `chr(0b00000001)` (binary) to make the bit value of the character more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing exactly how you're calling your code, but I'm assuming that you've done something like this:

```
sender = pulseSend()
sender.sendPulse('1')
```

As jasonharper mentions, that's wrong because you're sending the *text* `'1'`. Text is typically ASCII encoding (though in Python3 it's UTF). ASCII uses the numbers 0-255 (or `0000 0000` to `1111 1111`) to create characters. The character `'1'` is actually the integer 49:

```
>>> ord('1')
49
```

If you can send the actual integer value, that's great:

```
sender.sendPulse(1)
```

But you might not be able to, in which case (as jasonharper also mentions) you'll want to convert the int to its character value, which you do with `chr`. Here's some different ways you could write "send the string that corresponds to binary `0000 0001`":

```
sender.sendPulse('\x01')  # using the hex escape code
sender.sendPulse(chr(1))  # the integer 1, so `1111 1111` would be 255
sender.sendPulse(chr(0x01))  # hex literal
sender.sendPulse(chr(0b01))  # Binary literal. Could also be 0b00000001. You could use `0b0000_0001` or `0b_0000_0001` in Python 3.6+
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I wasn't sure how to send `0000 0001` rather than the character 1. I have to assign `pulseValue` in the eyetracker GUI - there is no code available to be with `sender.sendPulse(pulseValue)` unfortunately. Is there a way I can convert this value into what I need with something like `self.serial.write(chr(pulseValue))`? (Though of course this example would send `1111 1111`).

Comment: It would be much easier if I could use one of your examples, but am I right in thinking I need to use the variable `pulseValue` in some way as it has been passed to the class?

Comment: Update: I just used a serial port tester, and didn't realise that even though I configured the COM1 port correctly on the computer, different software way still use a different bit rate, etc. After configuring the port tester, the machine I need to trigger could differentiate between different characters, which is excellent. `self.serial.write(chr(pulseValue))` should work, but I'm currently receiving some python library errors. Will update once it's working!

Comment: @E_Williams you *must* be instantiating (or someone is) `pulseSend`. That will look like `pulseSend()` *somewhere* in the code. You can't really (you can but you really *really* shouldn't) use `sendPulse` without doing that. When you do `sender`(or whatever)`.sendPulse('\x01')` *you* are passing in the `pulseValue`. You're setting it. Then the function, as it's written, is writing that off to the serial port.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I meant was the only code I have access to in the eye-tracking software is the custom class I create, so I couldn't see any pulseSend(). I've edited the code a bit so that I don't have to pass pulseValue and simply write what I want to send.
I'll post the code in a comment below, but no matter which way I try to send 1, the serial device registers 2 separate messages. However, when I use ComTestSerial to send 1, it registers a single message containing 1. The options I've tried are:
`('\x01')
(chr(1))
(chr(0x01))
(chr(0b01))
(1)
('1')
(0x01)`

Comment: `import sreb
import serial

class SerTrigger(sreb.EBObject):
 def __init__(self):
  sreb.EBObject.__init__(self)
  self.ser = None
  baud_rate = 115200
  parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
  stop_bits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
  bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS

 def serOpen(self, port):
  self.ser  = serial.Serial(port)
  
 def sendMSG(self):
  self.ser.write(str(1))
  
 def serClose(self):
  self.ser.close()`

Comment: @E_Williams comments aren't for code blocks - if you've got some more code and this doesn't quite answer your question you should edit your original question.